# sum of integer variables in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
$sql_cerca2=$data2->query("SELECT * FROM ordine_bevanda WHERE cliente='".$_SESSION['conto_cliente']."' AND pagato='".'0'."';");
$res2=$data2->estrai($sql_cerca2);

while($cerca_obj2 = $data2->estrai($sql_cerca2)) {

    $bevanda=stripslashes($cerca_obj2->bevanda);
    $data3= new mysqlclass();
    $data3->connetti();
    $data = new MysqlClass();
    $data->connetti();
    $sql_cerca = $data->query("UPDATE ordine_bevanda SET pagato = '1' WHERE cliente=' ".$_SESSION['conto_cliente']."'");
    $sql_cerca3=$data3->query("SELECT * FROM offerta_bevanda WHERE bevanda='".$bevanda."' AND attiva='".'1'."';");
    $data4= new mysqlclass();
    $data4->connetti();
    $sql_cerca4=$data4->query("SELECT * FROM bevanda WHERE id='".$bevanda."';");

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql_cerca3)==0) {

        while ($cerca_obj4 = $data4->estrai($sql_cerca4)) {
            $nome=stripslashes($cerca_obj4->nome);
            $alcolica=stripslashes($cerca_obj4->alcolica);
            $prezzo=stripslashes($cerca_obj4->prezzo);
            echo 'Bevanda: '.$nome.'   Alcolica: '.$alcolica.'%   Prezzo: '.$prezzo.' euro<br>';
        }


    } elseif (mysql_num_rows($sql_cerca3)>0) {
        while ($cerca_obj3 = $data3->estrai($sql_cerca3)) {

            $acquistati=stripslashes($cerca_obj3->acquistati);
            $omaggio=stripslashes($cerca_obj3->omaggio);

            //echo 'acquistati: '.$acquistati.' omaggio: '.$omaggio;
            $acq = 0;
            $om = 0;
            $acquistati=intval($acquistati);
            $omaggio=intval($omaggio);
            while ($cerca_obj4 = $data4->estrai($sql_cerca4)) {

                //if(is_int($om))

                $acq=intval($acq);
                $acq+=1;
                //echo $acq.'<br>';

                $nome=stripslashes($cerca_obj4->nome);
                $alcolica=stripslashes($cerca_obj4->alcolica);
                $prezzo=stripslashes($cerca_obj4->prezzo);
                echo $prezzo.'<br>';

                if ($acq == ($acquistati + 1)) {

                    $prezzo=0;
                    //if(is_int($om))
                    $om+=1;

                 } elseif($om>$omaggio) {

                    $prezzo=stripslashes($cerca_obj4->prezzo);

                 } elseif($om<$omaggio && $acq>($acquistati + 1)) {

                    $prezzo=0;
                    //if(is_int($om))
                    $om+=1;

                 }

                //echo 'acquistati: '.var_dump($acq).' omaggio: '.var_dump($om).'<BR>FISSATI acquistati: '.var_dump($acquistati).' omaggio: '.var_dump($omaggio).'<br>';
                echo 'acquistati: '.$acq.' omaggio: '.($om).'<BR>FISSATI acquistati: '.($acquistati).' omaggio: '.($omaggio).'<br>';
                //echo 'acquistati: '.is_int($acq).' omaggio: '.is_int($om).'<BR>FISSATI acquistati: '.is_int($acquistati).' omaggio: '.is_int($omaggio).'<br>';

                //$sum = 0;
                //for ( $i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
                //    
                //    $sum = $sum+1 ;
                //    echo $sum.'-';
                //}

                //echo $sum;
                echo 'Bevanda: '.$nome.'   Alcolica: '.$alcolica.'%   Prezzo: '.$prezzo.' euro<br>';
                //if(is_int($om))
            }
        }   
    }
    $totale=$totale+$prezzo;
}
```

because the variables are not incremented?

`OUTPUT:`

```
5
acquistati: 1 omaggio: 0
FISSATI acquistati: 3 omaggio: 1
Bevanda: Vodka lemon Alcolica: 7% Prezzo: 5 euro
5
acquistati: 1 omaggio: 0
FISSATI acquistati: 3 omaggio: 1
Bevanda: Vodka lemon Alcolica: 7% Prezzo: 5 euro
5
acquistati: 1 omaggio: 0
FISSATI acquistati: 3 omaggio: 1
Bevanda: Vodka lemon Alcolica: 7% Prezzo: 5 euro
5
acquistati: 1 omaggio: 0
FISSATI acquistati: 3 omaggio: 1
Bevanda: Vodka lemon Alcolica: 7% Prezzo: 5 euro

Totale da pagare: 20 euro
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: U just posted ur code and forgot to post the question!

Comment: This code is such a mess. My advice is to use english named variables.

Comment: increase in the cycle variables om $ and $ acq but when I print the value remains the same as ever?

Comment: The cycle for 4 times but the values of and $om e $acq remain the same.

Comment: what if you remove the $acq = 0;   $om = 0; lines in your loop?

Comment: does not enter in if

Answer (score 0):

After the line:

```
echo 'acquistati: '.$acq.' omaggio: '.($om).'<BR>FISSATI acquistati: '.($acquistati).' omaggio: '.($omaggio).'<br>';
```

Please reset the parameters and try again like:

```
$acq = ""; $om = ""; $acquistati = ""; $omaggio = "";
```

Comment: please paste a few of your db table lines and db so that we can test it and solve the problem.